# Mootools: wizard plugin

Tags: javascript, mootools, webui

There is a plugin for moootols that applied to a form change it into a wizard?

Edit: No other responses to the question... I will accept mine.

Comment: A wizard of what? What should it be doing in your opinion? 

If Validation is what you have in mind than, you might want to check this: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Validator

Comment: For me a wizard is something similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_%28software%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's say there aren't plugins to transform a Form into a wizard.

I wrote one myself. It is available at http://github.com/eineki/FormWizard

Maybe it will be useful for somebody (beside me, obviously)

Comment: Link http://liberosoftware.net/FormWizard/ has more details on the same FormWizard with samples.